# Why does this method that throws an exception not have to be in a try catch block when invoked?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I invoke a method that throws exceptions, but I don't need to place this method inside a try catch block in static void main(String args[]), even though this tutorial says I should get an error. Why is this? Below is my code and a link to the tutorial. I played around with the second example in the tutorial.

https://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/java-throws/?unapproved=133049&moderation-hash=486e9de11daa2c67068e84cdacd88794#comment-133049

```
public class Sample2 {

    static void myMethod() throws ArithmeticException, NullPointerException {

        System.out.println("myMethod has been successfully called");

        throw new ArithmeticException("Arithmetic Expression has been thrown");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        myMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: The listed exceptions are `RuntimeException`s.

Comment: Only checked exceptions are *required* to be caught or declared to be thrown, but that doesn't mean that a method cannot declare that it throws an unchecked exception.

Comment: read the article **you** linked in the question - the very first sentence should help answering that question: "*As we know that there are two types of exception checked and unchecked. Checked exception (compile time) force you to handle them, if you don’t handle them then the program will not compile.*"

Comment: I read the article very carefully, but for someone just learning exceptions it can get confusing: This line of the article, just before the second example that I was referring to states "all the exceptions that are declared using throws, must be handled where you are calling this method else you will get compilation error.". That's a little confusing and not entirely correct, as @dasblinkenlight pointed out; the exceptions in the tutorial second example are unchecked ones, so they won't have an error unlike the tutorial states.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When talking about ***Exceptions in Java***, only 2 main types are invoked: ***checked exceptions*** and ***unchecked exceptions***.

The ***checked exceptions*** are checked in compile time: if you don't handle a checked exception (by using a try/catch block for example or the throws key word), the compiler will raise an error, in other words, it won't let you build your program, this is why you should always handle all the checked exceptions.

The ***unchecked exceptions*** are checked in runtime: your compiler will not raise an error if you don't handle these type of exceptions.

Now the question is: *how can i distinguish between these two types when i am coding ?*

You should first keep in mind that every exception in java should inherits from the ***"Exception" class***.

Now, there is a simple way you can tell a unchecked exception from a checked one: any exception class that inherits from ***"RuntimeException"*** is considered an ***unchecked exception***, and any class that inherits from ***"Exception"*** but not ***"RuntimeException"*** is considered is a ***checked exception***.

***In your case***, the method you're invoking throws a `ArithmeticException` and a `NullPointerException`. But this two exceptions inherits from the ***"RuntimeException"***. So, according to the rule written above, these 2 exceptions ***are unchecked exceptions***, and that's why you had no need to handle it when invoking your method `myMethod()`.

Answer (score 4):

The tutorial has a subtle mistake: although it clearly states that there is one kind of exceptions that does not need to be caught, it fails to notice that the exceptions thrown in their own examples are *unchecked*, i.e. of the `Runtime` variety:

> On the other hand unchecked exception (Runtime) doesn’t get checked during compilation. Throws keyword is used for handling checked exceptions.

Replace `ArithmeticException` with an exception that you derive directly from `Exception` to see the error.

Comment: I don't see how I didn't catch this, replacing the Exceptions with IOException gave me an error. Thank you!